# store image into a folder in netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, oracle10g, netbeans-7

I am using a FileChooser for selectiong image from the system.Now I want to store the image into db.For this I have created a new folder image in the project,and my idea is load the folder with the opened images renamed like  img1,img2...and store this path into the db, at a time one image.
I used the code below for getting the image name

```
String name = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

But I dont know how to store the image into the folder.Hope anyone will help to solve this.

Comment: Why save to the folder at all? Why not just directly to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the point of storing the images into your project jar. It would make more sense to save it into the system. But then again, why even do that?

Just store the image directly to the database. To do that just do this

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into imgtable values(?)");
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(fileFromChooser);  
ps.setBinaryStream(1,fin,fin.available());  

int i=ps.executeUpdate();  
System.out.println(i+" records affected");
```

---

**UPDATE**

Saving to File system. You need to specify the path in this line of code

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("C:\\path\\to\\destination\\" + file.getName()));
```

---

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class SaveImageFile {

    public SaveImageFile() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Save Image");

        JButton saveImage = new JButton("Browse");
        saveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "JPG, GIF, and PNG Images", "jpg", "gif", "png");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("You chose to open this file: "
                            + file.getName());
                    BufferedImage image;
                    try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(file);
                        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("C:\\path\\to\\destination\\" + file.getName()));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(SaveImageFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }              
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(saveImage);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SaveImageFile saveImageFile = new SaveImageFile();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: tryied this code.It shows error 'unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested'.

Comment: can you provide the code for just saving the image into the folder sir?Am handling large size images.So wish to store just that path

Comment: Is there any way to get the total no of images in the folder image?

Comment: Take a look at [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode%28int%29)

Comment: Sorry sir I didnt get.It shows method related to JFileChooser.But I need the no of images within the folder image inside the project where the new images saved

Comment: Get the directory. Use File.list() to return a String[]. get the length of it

Comment: Why in the world are you saving files to your project. That makes absolutely no sense. When you save a MS Word file, does it save to the Word Application? No, its saves to the file system.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47038/discussion-between-spc-and-peeskillet)

Answer (score 0):

The following code selects image and saves it into a folder. For more follow this link [How to save image in folder and path to database](https://youtu.be/6fljn8vMW4c)

```
 JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
 chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
 int res=chooser.showOpenDialog(ImageTutorial.this);
if(res==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
file=chooser.getSelectedFile();
String path=file.getAbsolutePath();
ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
Rectangle rec=imagelbl.getBounds();
Image scaledimage=image.getImage().getScaledInstance(rec.width,rec.height,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
image=new ImageIcon(scaledimage);
imagelbl.setIcon(image);
imagename.setText(file.getName());
 }else
  {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No new image selected");
  }
```